# Does the variance of a strictly monotonically increasing function of a random variable have anything to do with the variance of the random variable?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Assume that there is a continuous random variable *x*, and its variance is var(*x*). Furthermore, there is a strictly monotonically increasing function *f*. Can anybody prove that the larger the var(*x*), the larger the variance of *f*(*x*), i.e. var(*f*(*x*))? One thing important is that the expectation of this random variable is fixed, with its variance to be the only part changeable.

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem, and not a particularly well written one.  (In particular, immediately after stating the problem, you point out that it has an important hypothesis that is not part of the statement.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not true.  Take $f(x) = x^2$.  Let $X$ take the values $0$ and $4$ each with probability $1/2$, and $Y$ take the values $100$ and $102$ each with probability $1/2$.  Then we have $\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}\Var(X) = 4$ and $\Var(Y)=1$, but $\Var(f(X)) = 64$ and $\Var(f(Y)) = 40804$.

For an example going the other way, try $f(x) = x^{1/2}$.

Comment: But what about the situation where the random variable has a fixed expectation, say 0 or something else, but different variances?

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is still no even if all variables have mean zero.  Take $f(x)=x|x|$. 
Let $X$ take values $-5,-1,1,5$, equally likely, and let $Y$ take values $-4,4$, equally likely. Then $Y$ has greater variance than $X$ but this is reversed when you apply $f$ to both variables. 
All this remains true for continuous variables as well. Add an independent variable $U$, uniform in $[-\epsilon, \epsilon ]$, to both $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question again, and I want to know what will happen when the random variable is continuous.

Comment: @ddKong: Continuity won't change anything.  Replace each of the point masses with a normal distribution centered at the point and having very small variance.

Comment: PS if you keep changing the question, no one will answer your questions. Better to think hard and post another question after checking many examples.

Comment: It's my fault that I didn't think carefully before posting the question, and this will be the final version; at least the main content won't be altered.